# How to run one test method using a permanent run configuration

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've set up a few permanent run configurations in PyCharm.
[image: Run configurations]
To run an individual unit test I right click on the arrow next to that test in the gutter.

Before right clicking...
[image: Before right clicking]

After right clicking...
[image: After right clicking]

My question is, how do I select which run configuration to use to run this test? In the example above, I'd like to run this unit test with the *V2 Tests* config.

Is there a way to set a 'default' run configuration for all tests?

I've clicked all around PyCharm and searched the web multiple times and can't find an answer to this.